# Create and edit notes from mail client for MacOS notes app

Tags: macos, email, notes.app

My notes on my Notes App get transferred into a directory "Notes" on my mail account. When I open them [e.g. on my Android phone], they just look like simple mails, with text and a subject. But when I try to create or edit them manually on my phone, they just don't appear on my MacBook’s Notes App.

Is there some hidden magic I must do, to get that working?

Comment: Apple Notes isn’t exactly compatible with Android.  What you are seeing is the “workaround” so it’s working as expected.  It’s better to getba cross platform note taking app like OneNote that has macOS, Windows, iOS and Android apps.

Comment: Hmm, but macOS saves the notes to my mail account and restores it from there if, let's say, I setup my Macbook from scratch?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean if Apple Notes can recreate my notes from my email account, than it must be a deterministic way to create and read the notes. I just want to understand what I need to do, to create valid notes that Apple Notes can read.